# Type Script and Scaling with js require

Tags: typescript

Right now in the samples,  I see that you can use require in main.ts. There becomes a scale issue with browsers on how many calls can be made at one time.

I would like to structure the code with either a MVC or MPV structure.  And each module would then inject the requires js files.

If we have 300 ts files.  How would one structure the project so that the module can inject the required js files when needed and not have all in main/app.ts?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in TypeScript quite easily using the requirejs definitions though: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/requirejs

Sample:

```
require(['lazyLoad'], (lazyLoadedModule: any) => {
    // Use your lazyLoadedModule here.
});
```

Combine with AMD: Import as normal, but do not use the imported variable for anything but the type information:

```
import lazyLoadModule = require('./lazyLoad');
if (needZipValidation) {
    require(['./lazyLoad'], (lazyLoad: typeof lazyLoadModule) => {
        if (lazyLoadModule.somethingETC('...')) { /* ... */ }
    });
}
```